# Point cloud data on a grid

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, vector-grid, point-cloud

I have a point database marking different locations (presence of an animal) on a grid of 250 m x 250 m over a certain period of time. Each one of these points have a date.

By intersecting the grid file with the point shapefile I can calculate how many points are in each square of my grid. What I'm trying to figure out is how to calculate (and show) for how many days the animal was present in each square of my grid. Is it possible? (I don't have the pro-license)

Comment: Thank you. I now tried the summary statistic on the intersect file as you suggested, but it only gives me the amount of points in each square, so I can't really see how many days was the animal on the square (the problem is that points with the same date on the same square should be calculated as 1, but I don't know how to do it...)

Comment: Try to dissolve points based on shape and time fields.

Comment: Thank you very much! that worked out dissolving the points based on time fields.